# Generalising 4 methods in java

Tags: java, generics, methods

Suppose we have the following methods:

```
private boolean elephantExists(String name){
    for (Elephant e : elephantList) {
        if (e.getElephantName().equals(name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean elephantIDExists(String elephantID){
    for (Elephant e : elephantList) {
        if (e.getElephantID().equals(elephantID)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean tigerIDExists(String tigerID){
    for (Tiger t : tigerList) {
        if (t.getTigerID().equals(tigerID)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean dogIDExists(String dogID){
    for (Dog d : dogList) {
        if (d.getDogID().equals(dogID)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How are we able to generalise all these methods into one method?

I thought about doing something like this:

```
private boolean ifExists(String s, ArrayList<Object> arrList) {
    for (Object o : arrList) {
        if (something) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

However I am not sure what the if statement would be. I am having trouble generalising this and would appreciate the help :)

Comment: Make all your animal classes implement the same interface like `IDAware` which would provide a method `getId()`. Then you could pass a `List<T extends IDAware>` and search in it using `IDAware.getId()`.

Comment: Override equals method to check object id and check for collection.contains(object) where collection is collection containing objects an object an instance of the object type with the ID you are looking for.

Comment: @PauGómez Overriding `equals` to check only `id` just for this search is a misuse of `equals` on my book. Only checking the `id` is probably wrong semantics for `equals`. And what if there will be a need to search by other properties like `name` or `weight`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward would be to define an interface like `IdAware`:

```
public interface IdAware { public String getId(); }
```

Then make all your animal classes implement this interface. This will require renaming methods like `getTigerId()` to `getId()`, but that's a small sacrifice.

Then you could use this method to search in a list of animals. Something like:

```
private <T extends IdAware> boolean ifExists(String id, Collection<T> animals) {
    return animals.stream().anyMatch(animal -> id.equals(animal.getId()));
}
```

Alternatively if you for some reason don't want to (or cannot) have a common interface, you can additionally pass a lambda which extracts the id.

```
private <T> boolean ifExists(String id, Collection<T> animals, Function<T, String> getId) {
    return animals.stream().map(getId).anyMatch(animalId -> id.equals(animalId));
}
```

Then call it like `ifExists("Scott", tigers, Tiger::getTigerId);`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an Animal base class like this:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract String getId();
    abstract String getName();
}
```

Then make all the others extend it:

```
class Elephant extends Animal {

    @Override
    String getId() {
        // do logic
    }

    @Override
    String getName() {
          // do logic
    }
}

class Tiger extends Animal{

    @Override
    String getId() {
         // do logic
    }

    @Override
    String getName() {
          // do logic
    }
}


class Dog extends Animal {

    @Override
    String getId() {
        // do logic
    }

    @Override
    String getName() {
          // do logic
    }
}
```

now you can add any object of type `Animal` into the `ArrayList<Animal>` and pass it to the `ifExists` method along with the criteria.

```
private static boolean ifExists(Predicate<Animal> predicate, List<Animal> arrList) {
        for (Animal animal : arrList) {
            if (predicate.test(animal)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

now you can do:

```
ifExists(tiger -> tiger.getId().equals("007464"), arrList);
ifExists(elephant -> elephant.getId().equals("00D37464"), arrList);
ifExists(elephant -> elephant.getName().equals("Bo-Tat"), arrList);
ifExists(dog -> dog.getId().equals("008483"), arrList);
....
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not too acquainted with Java 8 and you are looking for a simplistic answer. Here's the code:

```
class AnimalId{
private String id;
public String getId(){ return this.id; }
}

class Elephant extends AnimalId{
//Other variables and function
}
class Tiger extends AnimalId{
//Other variables and function
}
class Dog extends AnimalId{
//Other variables and function
}
```

This covers the generalisation that you need. Now coming to your actual code, it would be something like this:

```
private boolean ifExists(String s, ArrayList<AnimalId> arrList) {
    for (AnimalId o : arrList) {
        if (o.getId.equals(s)) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```